# git grepping on filenames

Tags: git, git-grep

How can I pipe to `git grep` a list of files on which I want to search a specific pattern?
Specifically I do this:

```
git grep -l 'string to search'
```

and I want to do another `git grep` on the result files of the previous search.

Trying

```
git grep -l -e 'string to search' --and -e 'another string'
```

does not give any results but I know there are matches

Doing

```
git grep -l 'string to search' | git grep -l 'another string'
```

gives the same result as `git grep -l 'another string'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You can't *pipe* the names, but you can *supply* the names (as pathspecs) to one of the two `git grep` commands.

(Oddly, the `--and` should have done what you wanted in the first place—I'm just answering the question of how to do it without `--and`.)

#### Moderately long

It's not clear precisely what result you'd like, but on the assumption that what you want is:

- for each file in (some commit | some set-of-commits | the index | the work-tree)

  - if the file contains pattern 1
  - *and* the file contains, anywhere else in the same file (not necessarily on the same line) pattern 2
  - then list the file's name

there are two somewhat obvious ways to attempt to make that happen, but one of them doesn't work because Git won't match across newlines.<sup>1</sup>  So we're left with the other obvious method:

- First, use `git grep -l` to produce a *list of files* matching the first expression.
- Then, use `git grep -l` to produce a *list of files* matching the second expression, optionally, starting only with those files produced by the first `git grep`.

To combine these as an *and* operation, you have the fairly obvious option of using one of the two `git grep -l` outputs as a series of pathname arguments to the other `git grep`.  Note, however, that `git grep` takes *pathspec* arguments, rather than path *name* arguments, after the `--` that delimits them (see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) for details).  This means that if any of your file names have pathspec metacharacters in them, this simple shell expansion may fail.  It's also probably a good idea to verify that the first `grep` actually lists some files, but combining them into one bash style command:

```
git grep -l pattern2 -- $(git grep -l pattern1)
```

may often suffice.

To combine the above two as an *or* operation (list files that contain either pattern), it's easiest to just use one `git grep` with more than one pattern.  Note, however, that you can run multiple `git grep -l` operations with the resulting file names directed to a temporary file, then use a program like `comm` to report what's common and unique to each set of results.  (This assumes you have `comm` in your command-line-interpreter toolbox.)  Using `comm` also gets around the pathspec issues with peculiar file names like `(top)file.c` or `got*you.sh` or whatever.

---

<sup>1</sup>If Git *did* match across newlines, you could use the extended or Perl pattern: `(foo(.|\n)*bar)|(bar(.|\n)*foo)` to allow arbitrary text between the two other patterns `foo` and `bar`, with either pattern in either order.

Answer (score 3):

Your second `git grep` doesn't take the result of the first as an argument, it only outputs what it's supposed to, regardless of the first command.

Replace it with a simple bash grep and it should do

```
git grep -l 'string to search' | grep 'another string'
```

Comment: So it is impossible to do this with `git grep`?

Comment: @Jim I don't say that, I was just suggesting a way to modifiy your second attempt to achieve the objective. I'm unsure if you could have had the same result without pipe, just with `git grep` options, and I too find it interesting, I'll keep an eye here in case someone comes up with an idea.

Comment: and this only works, if 'another string' is in the same line as 'string to search'. If you want to search the entire files you could do something like:

git grep 'string to search' | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort | uniq | xargs git grep 'another string'